# Summing totals from 3 related tables to parent table - SQL

Tags: sql, join, subquery

I have a work order table with 3 related tables for labor, equipment, and materials.  I am trying to sum the cost for the 3 items and group by WorkOrderID.  I know a straight join will multiply all of the results so I need to use sub queries, but I cannot figure out how to write any of the sub queries.

Below is the broken straight join query.  I've tried a few sub queries and keep getting multiplied results.  Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

```
select wo.workorderid, sum(lab.cost) as labcost, sum(mat.cost) as matCost, sum(eq.cost) as eqcost
 from WORKORDER as wo
    join LABORCOSTACT as lab
 on lab.WORKORDERID = wo.WORKORDERID
    join MATERIALCOSTACT as mat
 on mat.WORKORDERID = wo.WORKORDERID
    join EQUIPMENTCOSTACT as eq
 on eq.WORKORDERID = wo.WORKORDERID
 where lab.TASKNAME like 'tree_rmvl'
group by wo.WORKORDERID
order by wo.WORKORDERID
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? SQL is just a query language not the name of a specific database product

Comment: Sample data.  Desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want avoid possible duplication you could join the aggreated  result  from the each table group by the key for join the main table

```
select wo.workorderid, lab.tot_lab_cost as labcost, mat.tot_mat_cost as matCost, eq.tot_eq_cost) as eqcost
from WORKORDER as wo
  inner join  ( 
        select WORKORDERID , sum(cost) tot_lab_cost
        from LABORCOSTACT 
        group by WORKORDERID
    ) lab on lab.WORKORDERID = wo.WORKORDERID
  inner join (
        select WORKORDERID , sum(cost) tot_mat_cost
        from MATERIALCOSTACT
        group by WORKORDERID
    ) mat on mat.WORKORDERID = wo.WORKORDERID
  inner join (
        select WORKORDERID , sum(cost) tot_eq_cost
        from EQUIPMENTCOSTACT
        group by WORKORDERID
     ) eq on eq.WORKORDERID = wo.WORKORDERID
 where lab.TASKNAME like 'tree_rmvl'
order by wo.WORKORDERID
```